# Program to generate numbers, finding average and largest values and rounding the largest to 100

Tags: c, array

As this code is not in English, I will explain it first:

- Creates ten numbers in an array between 0 and 100 as student grades.
- Calculates the largest number and average value of these ten numbers in the array.
- 100, the largest grade, is subtracted from the largest number in the array. (e.g 100-96=4)
- New value (which is 4 in this case, explained in example above) is added to all numbers in the array. It's also printed just below average value and largest value.
- New values in the array that are unable to surpass the average value are printed down below, which prints a sentence in Turkish that roughly translates to:

  ```
  "%dth student with %d grade has failed the lesson by staying under the average value."
  ```

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

int sum=0,fark,avg,imax;
int puan[10];
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
    puan[i]=rand()%101;
    printf("%d. ogrencinin notu = %d ",i+1,puan[i]);
    printf("\n");
    if(i==0) 
    {
        imax=puan[i];
    }
    else if(puan[i]>imax) 
        {
            imax=puan[i];
        }
    sum += puan[i];
}
avg=sum/10;
fark= 100 - imax;
printf("\nEn yuksek not = %d ve not ortalamasi %d.\n",imax,avg);
printf("Her ogrencinin notuna %d puan eklendi.\n",fark);
printf("\n");
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
    puan[i] += fark;
}
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
{
    if(puan[i]<avg) 
    {
        printf("%d. ogrenci aldigi %d notuyla ortalamanin altinda kalarak dersten basarisiz olmustur.\n",i+1,puan[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Can I shorten this code? Is there a shorter way to make it work in the same way? This was the best my friend and I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Just a **quick** approach. It could be **improved** more. What you want is a way to reduce the two loops into one.

Some comments about the code: We initialized imax in order to reduce the if -else statement and also we combined the 2 foor loops in the end into one. What I would like to achieve even more is to reduce the final two for loops into one. But I think this is not possible for this case. But I might be wrong.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int sum = 0, imax = 0;
    int puan[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        puan[i]=rand()%101;
        printf("%d. ogrencinin notu = %d \n",i+1,puan[i]);
        if(puan[i]>imax) 
        {
            imax=puan[i];
        }
        sum += puan[i];
    }
    float avg=sum/10.0f;
    int fark = 100 - imax;
    printf("\nEn yuksek not = %d ve not ortalamasi %f.\n",imax,avg);
    printf("Her ogrencinin notuna %d puan eklendi.\n\n",fark);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        puan[i] += fark;
        if(puan[i]<avg) 
        {
                printf("%d. ogrenci aldigi %d notuyla ortalamanin altinda kalarak dersten basarisiz olmustur.\n",i+1,puan[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Due to the nature of this kind of question, you can not reduce the loop to one. Two scans of the array is a must.

Comment: @phynju Yes! We needed a float to measure correctly the average! Nice touch. I like keeping the variables as close to where they are needed and not declaring at the top but that is not important.

Comment: @chux Yes you are correct. Thanks. Changed it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.  I can see quite a few improvements on the original that you haven't explained (e.g. initialising `imax` to avoid the `if`/`else`, combining `printf()` calls into a single one.  It's not really a review if you don't provide the commentary that helps a developer improve.

Answer (score 0):

To shorten, initialize `imax` to the minimum value.

Use macros to add clarity

```
#define CLASS_N 10
#define SCORE_MIN 0
#define SCORE_MAX 100
#define S_STUDENT_GRADE "ogrencinin notu"

int imax = SCORE_MIN;
for(int i=0; i < CLASS_N; i++) {
  puan[i] = rand()%(SCORE_MAX - SCORE_MIN + 1) + SCORE_MIN;
  printf("%d. " S_STUDENT_GRADE " = %d\n", i+1, puan[i]);

  // if(i==0) no need for this test

  if (puan[i] > imax) {
    imax = puan[i];
  }
  sum += puan[i];
}
```

---

The adjustment is not truly needed.  Add to the computation instead.

```
// for(int i=0;i<10;i++) { puan[i] += fark; }
for(int i=0; i < CLASS_N; i++) {
  if (puan[i] + fark < avg) {
    printf("%d. ogrenci aldigi %d ....\n", i+1, puan[i] + fark);
  }
}
```

---

Unclear if OP's code is functionally correct.  I would not expect the `fark` to change those students who are under the average.  Either the average is incremented by `fark` or the 50% compare does not include `fark`.

---

Note also the `float` math is not needed.  Still I do recommend FP.

```
printf("ve not ortalamasi %d.\n", sum/CLASS_N);
// or
int avg = sum*100/CLASS_N;
printf("ve not ortalamasi %d.%02d\n", avg/100, arg % 100);

...
if (puan[i]*CLASS_N < sum) {
```

Comment: I think he/she wants to give some poor performance students Christmas bonus. What a kind teacher.

Comment: @phynju So with scores 30,30,30...,30,30,30,40, everyone one is above average?  Kind perhaps.

Comment: So?  Do you really want to fail all your lovely students?

Comment: Of course not, all _my_ students are "above  average".  That 30,30,...40 was all lies and viscous gossip.

Comment: @CiaPan Yes - post amended.